# Write a function to check if two lists have the same elements in them in same order or not

Tags: kdb

Please help me with any better solution to find same elements in them same order on any two lists.

```
q)list3:(`red`green`black`orange)
q)list4:(`red`pink`green`white`black)
q)list5:(`white`orange`pink`black)

q)r:(inter/)(list3;list4)
q)all (list3?r) <= list4?r
1b

q)r:(inter/)(list4;list5)
q)all (list4?r) <= list5?r
0b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
q){i~x inter i:y inter x}[list4;list5]
0b
q){i~x inter i:y inter x}[list3;list4]
1b
q){i~x inter i:y inter x}[list4;list3]
1b
```